# Unable to get value of OpenGL ES 2 shader float uniform on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, opengl-es, raspberry-pi

I would like pass to my vertex shader a float as a uniform because each vertex will use the same value for this parameter. It works well on my computer (linux/gles) but on a Raspberry Pi, value at execution time are not correct at all.
I use bcm_host.h and EGL to setup my OpenGL context.

I have written a simple code to demonstrate this. It should show a blue triangle during 1s then a red one, then a blue one...

No OpenGL error is set during the execution on the Pi but the triangle stays blue.
I've look for the value with some graphicals tests and it looks like to be a little negative float number.

It is strange because I use uniforms for matrices and theses work well.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 100
precision mediump float;

uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
uniform mat4 modelview_matrix;
uniform float test;

attribute vec3 a_Vertex;
varying vec4 color;

void main( void )
{
    if( test == 500.0 )
        color = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    else
        color = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    gl_Position = projection_matrix * modelview_matrix * vec4( a_Vertex, 1.0 );
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 100
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 color;

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

C++ display code:

```
    if( ticks - lastDrawTicks > 1000 )
    {
        Screen::get()->clear();

        program->use();
        program->sendUniform( "projection_matrix", projection, false );
        program->sendUniform( "modelview_matrix", modelview, false );

        if( value )
        {
            int location = glGetUniformLocation( program->getId(), "test" );
            CheckOpenGLError(glGetUniformLocation);

            Logger::get() << location << " <- Red !" << Logger::endl;

            glUniform1f( location, 500.0f );
            CheckOpenGLError(glUniform1f);

            //program->sendUniform( "test", 500.0f );
            value = false;
        }
        else
        {
            int location = glGetUniformLocation( program->getId(), "test" );
            CheckOpenGLError(glGetUniformLocation);

            Logger::get() << location << " <- Blue !" << Logger::endl;

            glUniform1f( location, 0.0f );
            CheckOpenGLError(glUniform1f);

            //program->sendUniform( "test", 0.0f );
            value = true;
        }

        program->sendVertexPointer( "a_Vertex", vbo );

        ibo->draw();

        Screen::get()->render();

        lastDrawTicks = ticks;
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Using "glUniform1fv" instead of "glUniform1f" is working.

```
float fvalue = 500.0f;
glUniform1fv( location, 1, &fvalue );
```

Comment: I'm assuming that `program->use()` directly calls `glUseProgram(getId())`, am I right?

Comment: Yes, it checks for errors too and it enables attributes if any.

Comment: If `glUniform1fv()` is working with the same value, that strongly suggests a bug in the OpenGL implementation.

Comment: use `glsllang` - a reference compiler and compile your shader. You can get `uniform reflection` of compiled binary. If that is working fine, you can confirm its a bug with the implementation, probably false optimization.

Comment: @Adorn If setting the uniform with `glUniform1fv` works, but `glUniform1f` fails for the same uniform, it probably has nothing to do with the shader code.

Comment: exactly, thats what I am trying to say. But currently this is our best guess. You can confirm this guess using `glsllang` and get value which is assigned to uniform in the shader. After this you can report a bug